# Calculating pointer deltas in mouse drag events with Rx API

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, system.reactive

I'm trying to create a game UI with *Rx* API ([UniRx](https://github.com/neuecc/UniRx) to be specific), and having difficulty in trying to get rid of global state variables.

The UI has two drag handles with which you can control camera rotation and height respectively. And I wrote following code to handle drag events:

```
Action<IPointerDragAware, Vector3> register = (button, direction) =>
{
    var events = button.OnDrag.Select(v => v.position);

    Observable.Zip(events, events.Skip(1))
        .Select(v => v[1] - v[0])
        .Select(v => Normalize(v, direction))
        .Subscribe(OnDrag)
        .AddTo(this);

    // I want to remove this hack.
    button.OnDragEnd
        .Subscribe(_ => _dragFinished = true)
        .AddTo(this);
};

register(RotateButton, Vector3.right);
register(MoveButton, Vector3.up);

private void OnDrag(Vector2 delta)
{
    // And this too...
    if (_dragFinished)
    {
        _dragFinished = false;
        return;
    }

    // Code to move camera around follows...
}
```

The reason why I needed the *_dragFinished* hack was to prevent a spike in camera movement when I drag one button then drag the other, because the current code just calculates pointer deltas without considering if they are from the same continuous drag action or not.

I tried comparing timestamps, but put *.Where* filter to the zipped event stream made it hang. Probably I'm doing something wrong, but I'm still new to *Rx* API so I'm pretty much stuck right now.

So, I'd appreciate if anyone could give me some hints as to how I can rewrite it to get rid of any member variables?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there always 2 `OnDrag` events followed by an `OnDragEnd` event? Perhaps you could buffer `OnDrag` events until `OnDragEnd` and work with that

Comment: @supertopi Not always, but I can safely ignore such a case where there's only a single drag event.

I thought about using TakeUntil with onDragEnd, but in that case I'm not too sure how I can start listening the event again (with Repeat maybe?)

Anyway, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var drags = button.OnDrag.Select(v => v.position);
var dragEnds = button.OnDragEnd;

drags.GroupByUntil(_ => true, _ => dragEnds)
     .SelectMany(b => b.ToList())
     .Where(i => i.Count == 2) //could be less, could be more...
     .Select(i => Normalize(i[1]-i[0], direction))
     .Subscribe(OnDrag)
     .AddTo(this);
```

`GroupByUntil` + `SelectMany` combo returns lists of OnDrag events between OnDragEnd events.
Button event observables are assumed to be hot.

Comment: Unfortunately though, it seems that UniRx doesn't support GroupByUntil, so I had to find an alternative which I'll write below.

But your answer helped me a lot to understand Rx better, and I think it should be considered the best solution in normal circumstances.

Thanks much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

For general solution, please refer to @supertopi's answer above. I managed to make it work by following code, because *UniRx* doesn't support *GroupByUntil* yet:

```cs
var events = button.OnDrag.Select(v => v.position);

Observable
    .Zip(events, events.Skip(1))
    .TakeUntil(button.OnDragEnd)
    .RepeatSafe()
    .Select(i => Normalize(i[1] - i[0], direction))
    .Subscribe(MoveCamera)
    .AddTo(this);
```